# Where do I place the qualification 'in part' in a sentence?

Tags: word-order

Where do I place the qualification 'in part' in a sentence? For example, is it

> - '[something] happened, **in part**, due to [...]'; or
> - '[something] happened due, **in part**, to [...]'; or
> - '[something] happened due to, **in part**, [...]'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them seems exactly wrong but I would prefer the second one which flows more naturally when read aloud. Note that for the first example the comma between *part* and *due* is incorrect. The third one is the worst of the three to my ears as it makes you make a more definite pause twice at the commas.